# Distribution of a fractional part of the sum of uniform RVs

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I had a question in class not long ago which I couldn't solve. I've been digging into it for a few hours now but I can't find the right direction. So the question is:

> Let $ U_1,..,U_n$ be I.I.D random variables with uniform distribution : $ U_i \sim U[0,1] $. I need to prove that the **fractional part** of their sum - $\sum_{i=1}^n U_i $ , is also uniformly distributed.

I know that this sum has the Irwin-Hall distribution, but not sure how it helps me.

Any ideas on this one?
Thanks.

Comment: Are we assuming that the $U_i$ are iid?

Comment: Indeed we are, sorry I didn't point it out . I will edit my post. Any ideas then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple argument by induction will also work.  If we define $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ as the fractional part of $x$, then proving that $\{U_1 + U_2\} \sim U \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$ will then allow you to inductively show the main result, because $$\{U_1 + \cdots + U_n\} = \{\{U_1 + \cdots + U_{n-1} \} + U_n \}$$ and each $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ are iid.  So all that remains is to prove the base case, which is quite straightforward as an explicit integral.  First, the distribution of $S_2 = U_1 + U_2$ is easily calculated:  $$f_{S_2}(s) = \begin{cases} s, & 0 \le s \le 1 \\ 2-s, & 1 < s \le 2. \end{cases}.$$  Then the CDF of $\{S_2\}$ is obtained by noting $$ F_{\{S_2\}}(s) = \Pr[\{S_2\} \le s] = \int_{u=0}^s f_{S_2}(u) \, du + \int_{u=1}^{1+s} f_{S_2}(u) \, du = s.$$

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify the last line?
The distribution of the sum $U_1 + U_2$ is clear, but I don't fully understand how the distribution of the fractional part is deduced by integrating on exactly the same PDF of the sum .

Comment: I recommend sketching the PDF of $S_2$, which looks like a triangle.  Then, think of the way you could have, for a given $s \in [0,1]$, $\Pr[\{S_2\} \le s]$:  in particular, there are two cases:  if $0 \le S_2 < 1$, then $\{S_2\} \le s$ is the same as saying $S_2 \le s$ since the fractional part of a number between 0 and 1 is just that number.  But if $1 \le S_2 < 2$, then $\{S_2\} = S_2 - 1$.  So you can now see how the integration works:  pay careful attention to the limits of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough and sloppy sketch of a proof. It should not be difficult to fill in any gaps.

Let $\{x\}$ refer to the fractional part of $x$.

First, we need the following fact $\{a_1+a_2\} = \{a_1\} + \{a_2\} - \lfloor \{a_1\}+\{a_2\}  \rfloor $.

Let us start with $\{\sum_{i=1}^n U_i\}$. The $U_i$'s are i.i.d uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$.

\begin{equation}
\{\sum_{i=1}^n U_i\} = \{U_1+U_2\} + \{\sum_{i=3}^n U_i\} - \lfloor \{U_1+U_2\} + \{\sum_{i=3}^n U_i\} \rfloor  \\
\end{equation}

Consider $\{U_1+U_2\}$. You can prove that $\{U_1+U_2\}$ is also uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. We will refer to this term as $\{V\}$ ($V$ and $\{V\}$ are interchangeable here). Therefore, we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\{\sum_{i=1}^n U_i\} &= \{V\} + \{\sum_{i=3}^n U_i\} - \lfloor \{V\} + \{\sum_{i=3}^n U_i\} \rfloor  \\
&=\{V + \sum_{i=3}^n U_i\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now, the RHS in the above equation is a sum of uniform random variables, so you can apply the above process again until you are left with only a single uniformly distributed random variable.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic function of the sum ($S_n$) of i.i.d. $U[0,1]$ random variables

$$\varphi_{S_n}(2\pi h)=\left(\frac{e^{2\pi h i}-1}{2\pi h i}\right)^n=0$$

for any $h\in\mathbb{Z}\text{\\} \{0\}$. Here is some [reference](http://www.ams.org/journals/tpms/2011-83-00/S0094-9000-2012-00841-7/S0094-9000-2012-00841-7.pdf).

Comment: What does this have to do with anything?

Comment: This refers to the Weyl criterion. The same arguments work here...

Comment: Although it looks convincing, is it possible a simpler approach exists for this particular case (IID uniform RVs)?